# RETURN value from other table using foreign key retrieved in query in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have built a query:

```
SELECT [Hours], TaskId FROM DailyTaskHours 
WHERE PointPerson = 'Dave Smith (smithd)' 
AND ActivityDate Between Cast('1/01/13 12:01:01' As DateTime) 
AND Cast('2/01/13 12:01:01' as DateTime)
```

This returns all of the hours as well as the associated taskId they are billed to. The TaskId is a forign key to the Task table. As part of the same query I want to return a column called Name and a column called StoryId that is on the Task table. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  D.[Hours], 
        D.TaskId,
        T.[Name],
        T.StoryId
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T
    ON D.TaskId = T.TaskId
WHERE D.PointPerson = 'Dave Smith (smithd)' 
AND D.ActivityDate Between Cast('1/01/13 12:01:01' As DateTime) 
AND Cast('2/01/13 12:01:01' as DateTime)
```

But you should always explicitely write the datetime format that you are using (`CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,Format`), and also the complete year. In your case, is `'2/01/13'` January 2nd 2013, February 1st 2013, January 2nd 1913?, etc. Also, try to avoid using `BETWEEN` when querying `DATETIME` data types ([Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries))